# Exclusive and inclusive filtering of attributes

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple filter function I have:

```
function filter (attributes, data, include) {
    if (include) {
        let res = {}
        if (typeof attributes === 'string') {
            res[attributes] = data[attributes]
            return res
        }
        if (attributes.length) {
            attributes.forEach(attr => res[attr] = data[attr])
        }
        return res
    } else {
        if (typeof attributes === 'string') {
            delete data[attributes]
            return data
        }
        if (attributes.length) {
            attributes.forEach(attr => delete data[attr])
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

As you can see, these parts are same:

```
if (typeof attributes === 'string') {
    // some code
    return // some variable
}
if (attributes.length) {
    attributes.forEach(attr => /* some code */)
}
return // some variable
```

What is the best way to remove this duplicated code?

Comment: The code is not similar, they're different. One is updating property value and other is deleting a property.

Comment: What I don't understand is on *include == true* you clone the data object with the results you want back, on *include == false* you modify the data object instead. It is a weird behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To @Tushar's point, those 2 code blocks are not similar. In fact, I would advise you to turn that function in to 2 functions with a better name. Especially since your function optionally depending on `include` modifies `data` which is not a good design. It should either always generate a new object, or always modify `data`. Probably it should always generate a new object.

Furthemore for greater flexibility, I would not check for `attributes.length` but for `attributes.forEach`, this way you know for sure the function/method is defined.

In Lodash the first function would be called `pick`, and the second function would be `omit`.

Thinking about this, if you are always going to build a new object, you could remove repetitive coding:

```
function filter(attributes, data, include) {
    'use strict';

    let keys = Object.keys(data),
        res = {};
    //Turn attributes into an array if needed
    attributes = (typeof attributes === 'string') ? [attributes] : attributes;
    keys.forEach(key => {
        //If its an attribute we include, get it
        //If its an attribute we dont exclude, get it
        if ((include && attributes.indexOf(key) != -1) ||
            (!include && attributes.indexOf(key) == -1)) {
            res[key] = data[key];
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The condition might be more readable as `include ^ (attributes.indexOf(key) === -1)`

Comment: I dont even know what that caret would do?

Comment: [XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR). Although I didn't realise that in JS it's bitwise, so the type coercion could cause unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I think from a CodeReview perspective `^` is definitely out. I get flack from this community for using bitwise NOT '~' even if it is a match made in heaven to use on the results of `indexOf()`